# How to retrieve value of IE field in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to retrieve "count of suppliers" from the html code, which I am failing.

[image]

I have tried:

```
Offers = IE.Document.getElementByID("offers")

Split(IE.Document.getElementByID("offers")

Set Offers = IE.Document.getElementByID("offers").IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

Set Offers = IE.Document.getElementByID("offers").IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-3")
```

followed by `For...Next` statement

And all its combinations with .Value, .innerText or (0)

The value 555 is in none of these options. I have no clue...

Comment: Does `getElementById("offers").getElementsByTagName("input")(0)` return anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
Offers = IE.Document.getElementByID("offers").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value
```